# Falha ao rodar um arquivo Python

Tags: python

Quero fazer esse codigo executavel pra usa-lo no crontab:

```
import data
import mensagem
from skpy import Skype

sk = Skype(data.USERNAME, data.PASSWORD)

def post_message_group(mensage, channel_id): 
    "Post a message for group" 
    group_mensage = sk.chats.chat(channel_id)
    group_mensage.sendMsg(mensage)

post_message_group(mensagem.mensage, data.CHANNEL_ID)
```

Quando executo ele com um `python /home/kali-john/Documentos/Projects/scripts/skype-mensage/main.py`
DA CERTO, ele envia a mensagem no skype

O problema quando eu rodo ele assim: `/usr/bin/python3.9 /home/kali-john/Documentos/Projects/scripts/skype-mensage/main.py` (Que é a forma que devo por no crontab), aparece o erro:

```
  File "/home/kali-john/Documentos/Projects/scripts/skype-mensage/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from skpy import Skype
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skpy'
```

Mesmo caminho, porém um jeito roda do outro da erro:
[image: Mesmo caminho, porém um jeito roda do outro da erro]

**Meu sistema todo ta com a versão python 3.9.0**

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0):

Você provavelmente precise configurar o PYTHONPATH, no crontab você pode executar um script que execute seu python program, porém antes tem que escrever o seguinte
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/lib
Onde o path indica o folder onde estão suas librerias

PS:não esqueça que no começo de cada py script é preciso escrever o seguinte: !#/usr/bin/env python3
Pode ser esse tb o problema se a libreria è uma libreria instalada.